# How can I remove the line above the tab bar that shows on iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's what I am trying to remove.  I thought it was already removed in earlier iOS but now in 13.3 I think it's back again:

[image]

Here is the renderer code I was using before:

```
    protected override IShellItemRenderer CreateShellItemRenderer(ShellItem item)
    {
        var renderer = base.CreateShellItemRenderer(item);
        (renderer as ShellItemRenderer).TabBar.Translucent = false;
        (renderer as ShellItemRenderer).TabBar.ShadowImage = new UIImage(); // <<<<<<<
        (renderer as ShellItemRenderer).TabBar.BackgroundImage = new UIImage();
        UITabBar myTabBar = (renderer as ShellItemRenderer).TabBar;

        foreach (var barItem in myTabBar.Items)
        {
            barItem.ImageInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(5, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        return renderer;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overriden method `CreateShellItemRenderer` can not get `Tabbar` now , it will return `null` . Therefore code can not work .

You can override **CreateTabBarAppearanceTracker** to get Tabbar in iOS 13 .As follow :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AppShellTab.AppShell), typeof(AppShellTab.iOS.MyShellRenderer))]
namespace AppShellTab.iOS
{
    public class MyShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {
        protected override IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker CreateTabBarAppearanceTracker()
        {
            return new MyOtherTabBarAppearanceTracker();
        }

        public class MyOtherTabBarAppearanceTracker : ShellTabBarAppearanceTracker, IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker
        {
            void IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker.SetAppearance(UITabBarController controller, ShellAppearance appearance)
            {
                base.SetAppearance(controller, appearance);
                var tabBar = controller.TabBar;
                tabBar.BackgroundImage = new UIImage();
                tabBar.ClipsToBounds = true;
                //tabBar.Translucent = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The effect :

[image]

Comment: Hello Junior,  You mention "The overriden method CreateShellItemRenderer can not get Tabbar now".  Can you confirm this for me as I was able to get the Tabbar and I am using the latest code.  Is that perhaps with version 4.5 that you cannot get tabbar.   I tried adding "tabBar.ClipsToBounds = true;" as you suggested and it worked good. Just like to get some confirmation to my question. Thanks very much

Comment: @Alan2 OK ,above code tested before version 16.4.5 , it works . I will check it with the latest version 16.4.5 .

Comment: Good thing is that it works good and if there are any issues then I also have your other suggestion in my code commented out but for the future.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Alan2 Okey , glad to hear that ! If other issues also can share in SO later .